# Passing an int pointer into a function to print that array in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

This is my first post so bear with me. I am getting back into writing in C after being out of school for a while. I am trying to pass an array of integers into a function that will print the entire array out on the same line (as a part of a larger effort). My dumbed down code follows:

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int arr[] = {3,4,5,6,7};
    int *ptr = arr;
    int l = 5;

    printarr(arr,l);
    return 0;
}
```

And

```
// function printarr
#include <stdio.h>

void printarr(char *ptr, int l) {

    int k = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < l; ++k) {
        printf("%d", ptr[k]);
    }
}
```

After compiling and running main.c, the output I get is:

```
30004
```

I feel like I have been beating my head against a wall trying to figure out a simple problem. When I iterate and print the array in main I get the output I would expect ('34567') but when I try to do it through the function it comes out sad. I suspect I am misusing the pointer but yeah I'm not sure.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks.

edit: Upon glancing at the first two comments, I am entirely ashamed of myself. Thank you folks. Wow, just wow.

Comment: Why does `printarr` take a `char *`?

Comment: `char *ptr` --> `int *ptr`. Also put prototype before use it.

Comment: It is absurd how much time I spent overlooking the obvious just now. My word. Thank you for the fresh eyes.

Comment: Put prototype where? Apologies, I would like to have proper forum etiquette but I do not quite understand what you mean.

Comment: @GGubs Put it before `main`. E.g `void printarr(int *ptr, int l); int main(void) {`

Comment: The prototype should go in a header file which is included by both C files, then there is not the possibility of getting it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your function to

```
void printarr(int *ptr, int l)
```

as you're passing an `int *` to it. As pointed by @Malife, you should enable the compiler warnings with [`-Wall`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall-304), so you get a proper message. Optionally make all warnings into errors with [`-Werror`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror-295).

`char` and `int` have different sizes, `int` being much bigger. 4 times bigger as you can see from your output. You're iterating the memory where your `int` numbers are allocated in a partial manner when looking at the values as `char`.

Comment: I compiled with gcc and oddly, I did not get a compiler error. Thank you for fleshing out the answer.

Comment: You would not get an error generally (unless you had the -Werror compiler option). But at least do make sure to add the -Wall compiler option. That will save you many headaches as you get reacquainted with C.

Answer (score 0):

printarr should be expecting an int array, not char array, so should be

```
 void printarr(int *ptr, int l)
```

In main, int *ptr = arr; is not used or needed.

You probally also want to put a space or new line between each value of the array you are printing out:

```
void printarr(char *ptr, int l) {

    int k = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < l; ++k) {
        printf("%d\n", ptr[k]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Many thanks. the *ptr is a vestige from the code I forked this from. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you pass a char pointer in "printarr". In fact when you pass "ptr" you have this situation: 00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100 .... A char has 8 bit, an int 32 bit, and the Ram is often Little Endian for the bytes order. Then you call a printf passing an int, and the byte is extended to 32 bits so you print: 3 0 0 0 4. In the main "ptr" is an int, so you print the int, in this case 3 4 5 6 7. You must change char *ptr -> int *ptr in "printarr"